# 2006 GSX 600F Suzuki Katana won’t engage starter

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starter, katana, gsx

Bought a used katana gsx600f 2006.cannot get it to turn over.battery good, Clutch lever engaged,kickstand up,push starter button,starter solenoid not clicking. Can short over relay & motor turns over.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Make sure your starter button is passing power ... sounds like the most likely place to start looking.

Comment: Have read other posts. Found clutch switch bad & kickstand switch inop. Bypassed both & engine turned over

Comment: If you've found your answer, please post it up, then select it as "the answer" ... helps us close out questions as well as bring important information here :o)

Answer (score 1):

Bought a used clutch lever with cable that you just pull off old & bolt this replacement. Diassembled old assembly & found someone previously changed out clutch lever only so all broken safety switch was still installed. Diassembled sidestand switch. It was corroded beyond repair, so will buy new one.

Answer (score -2):

check to see if your plugged in to the clutch lever. i had an issue and that was the problem.

Comment: Answers generally have a bit more information than this. Explain how the questioner can find the clutch lever "plug" that you talk about. Is it at the handle? Is it somewhere else?  Also, answers should be a mixture of general and specific information so they are useful to more than Katana GSX 600 riders. Your answer begins the process, but needs some expansion to fit people who ride Hondas or Harleys.